# MVC Core @User.Identity.Name in razor returns null

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

It runs just fine and returns the name on my local machine (windows authentication) by using @User.Identity.Name. However, if I move it from my local to dev server, it just returns the text without the name. Not sure why @User.Identity.Name doesn't work when I push.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse">
   <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">    
      <script id="greetings">
         document.write('Hello, ');
      </script>
      @User.Identity.Name
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check if you also enabled Anonymous Authentication on that dev server.

Comment: It is disabled. Only Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: ...my bad. Anonymous was on.. haha.. just got a new dns and set up all. Didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It runs just fine and returns the name in my local (windows authentication) by using @User.Identity.Name. However, if I move it from my local to dev server, it just returns the text without the name.

As we discussed in comments, if ***Anonymous Authentication*** is enabled, which will cause this issue.

Besides, we can check if the user is authenticated first, then display the name of current non-anonymous user in view page instead of accessing `User.Identity.Name` directly.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse">
    <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">
        <script id="greetings">
            document.write('Hello, ');
        </script>
        
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <span>@User.Identity.Name</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>Anonymous user</span>
        }

    </p>
</div>
```